# Variable scanf inputs

Tags: c, scanf

How exactly would you deal with having a variable amount of scanf inputs? 
I'm scanning commands, some of them are 1. word commands but some require numeric argument. Does scanf allow the following?

```
 scanf(" %s %d", command, argument);
```

Would that ignore the "argument" if only one value was inputed?
The other option i though of was

```
 scanf(" %s", command)
 if (strcmp(command, "somethin") {
      scanf("%d", argument); }
```

But that would create a newline right? the terminal has to recieve the input in form of "> command argument"
SO, my question is, how to solve the problem of having variable number of inputs.

Comment: The first one will just wait for you to type an argument. Read a line using `fgets()`, then use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Comment: You can also read the line and then use `strtok()` to split it into tokens, which you would then parse.

Comment: You almost certainly want to read a whole line and then process that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't "create a newline". `scanf` is completely unaware of any newlines. `scanf` treats the input stream as a linear sequence of data separated by whitespace. Newline is just whitespace, no different from any other whitespace. The only `scanf` format specifiers that can "see" newlines are `%c` and `%[]`. Your `%s` and `%d` are completely newline-agnostic.

Which means that your second example is doing it right (within the natural limitations of `scanf`). It won't "create a newline". It will read a single line, if you supply the input in a single line (like `somethin 42`).

You might actually run into the "opposite" problem: if the user forgets to input the required argument in a single line, the next scanf will wait for it on the next line. And on the next line. And on the next line... until he user finally supplies it. I'm not sure this behavior is desirable for you. If not, then a better idea would be to use dedicated line-based input through `fgets` and then parse the line manually.

P.S. There's no reason to prepend `%s` and `%d` with spaces.

Comment: Hmm, actually i tried it right now and it actually behaves somewhat weirdly. It managed to escape and infinite loop. It ignores the "if" test, simply goes into it ignoringess of what i input as the command and the proceeds to basicaly go ham on the inputs. EDIT: nvm fixed it. Misshandled the strcmp input.

Comment: @ZergOvermind `fgets` reads from a stream. You can specify `stdin` as that stream. In fact, `scanf` is essentially just a shorthand for `fscanf(stdin,...`